# Cannot bind to button events using x:Bind in DataTemplates - generates XAML error

Tags: xaml, binding, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, xbind

With the `{x:Bind}` markup syntax you can bind to events provided the method meets the following requirements:

- Match the signature of the event.
- OR have no parameters.
- OR have the same number of parameters of types that are assignable from the types of the event parameters.

This works perfectly fine outside of a DataTemplate. Once the binding happens inside the DataTemplate the compiler generates the following error:

> Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

What is the fix for binding to events inside DataTemplates?

Full example code [here](https://github.com/rmaclean/x-BindFun/tree/6d9856bf211dda1f8de92066a7ec1e8660f38ae0).

Snippet of the example code below - note the first button (line 2) is fine and the second button (line 6) is also fine. If you comment out line 6 and and comment in line 7, the error occurs.

```
 <StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button Tapped="{x:Bind Click}" Content="WORKING"/>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Names}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Customer"> 
                    <Button Content="{x:Bind Title}"/>
                    <!--<Button Tapped="{x:Bind Clicky}" Content="{x:Bind Title}"/>-->
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, do you get this xaml error in design time or as a runtime error? Also where does the `Clicky` event actually reside; is it found on the page's datacontext?

Comment: Compile time - won't actually build. `Clicky` resides  on the object instance, not the page's datacontext. If this was Command + ICommand I would do `{Binding Clicky}` to access it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get it to work with the following code:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Customer">
     <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
         <Button Tapped="{x:Bind Clicky}" Content="{x:Bind Title}" />
     </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

It seems as though you need to have it inside a container for it work. I have no idea why I am guessing magic.

Answer (score 0):

The parser cannot find `Clicky` from the datacontext of the button while in the template. Because the object that is being handed to the button in the template (*from the `Names` on the ItemSource of the parent*) is not the same as outside the template which has a `Clicky`. You will need to bind `Clicky` to the page's datacontext to get it to work.

---

Otherwise turn off any design time operations by setting `Tapped="{x:Bind Clicky, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}`.

Comment: If Clicky was on the pages DataContext, it is not possible with {x:Bind} because of this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32849864/alternative-to-elementname-in-xbind-with-datatemplates

However Clicky is on the context of the item that is bound so no traversal should be needed.

Comment: @RobertMacLean is the exception due to operations in `Clicky`? See update,

Comment: Nope - not with that at all. Happens when it compiles so not hitting design time stuff